# Get id of an organic group inside a view

Tags: views, nodes, organic-groups

How can i get the organic group id inside a view?
I tried to get it like this:

```
function HOOK_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['view']->name == 'MYVIEWSNAME') {
    $nid = $vars['view']->result[0]->nid;
    $node = node_load($nid);
    $og_id = $node->og_group_ref['und'][0]['target_id'];
    dpm($og_id); 
  }
}
```

This is printing the correct id to my devel debug,
but i cant access $og_id in my view-template.

Or maybe you got an other solution to create the /node/add/document .. link.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: I want to get some information about the nodes of a view. And print them inside the view. For example into the header section.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a corresponding template file in your sub-theme?

Themes cannot have a preprocess function without a corresponding .tpl.php file

https://drupal.org/node/258089